# MS SQL Server. Vietnamese symbols in varchar (not nvarchar) datatype columns

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have got a question about MS SQL Server 2012. I have got a database with default collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Now I decided to store Vietnamese data in varchar (not nvarchar) columns. To achieve this goal I have changed database collation to Vietnamese_CI_AI, but this hasn't helped me. Special Vietnamese characters are still represented as question marks.

After that I have tried to make an experiment - database collation was changed to Cyrillic_General_CI_AS (russian symbols), Korean_90_CI_AI (korean symbols) and Chinese_Traditional_Stroke_Count_100_CI_AI (chinese symbols). All of these cases completed successfully - all the data was saved in varchar columns proprerly.

Googling some information sources about this issue helped me to find this topic - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d34242e5-90ac-4c91-b720-66ebc6dca229/inserting-vietanamese-characters-in-sql-server?forum=sqldatabaseengine. As it said in the last comment there, it is not possible to store Vietnamese symbols in varchar data types, even you have changed collation to Vietnamese_CI_AI. So, to store Vietnamese data there is only one way - to use nvarchar datatype. I would like to know, is this information correct or is there any method to put Vietnamese data in varchar columns?

Certainly yours, Dmitriy

Comment: Vietnamese characters would have to be stored as nvarchar. Collation has nothing to do with what a given datatype can store. What is the concern with using nvarchar?

Comment: @SeanLange We have got an existing database with plenty of varchar columns, in which Vietnamese data should be placed. If it is impossible, I'll have to change all "varchar" datatypes to "nvarchar" in tables + all related database objects

Comment: Ugh that sounds kind of painful. But yeah you don't have much choice. If you need to store Vietnamese characters you have to use nvarchar instead of varchar.